# Couchdb on windows server 2012

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Is anyone using couchDB with windows server 2012.
Only version I could find is X86, is there version avilable for 64bit for download.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm using CouchDB(x86) with Windows Server 2012
2. No there is not a 64bit version for Windows.

Sources : http://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: Windows server 2012 R2 build is 64 bit, can we install CouchDB(x86) on 64 bit ?

Comment: 64 bit OS support 32bit. Therefore 32bit os doesn't support 64bit. So yes you can install it.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it.